# Jenkins Snyk plugin issue, artifacts are not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, snyk

I have a jenkins pipeline.
I am using Snyk security plugin
I have the following code
the following step to build and create a report file and publish it as artefact

```
 stage('Snyk Scan') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Execute the Snyk scan step
                snyk (
                    targetFile: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pype-snyk-nodejs/package.json',
                    reportFormat: 'xml',
                    reportFile: 'test.xml',
                    snykToken: credentials('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
                )
            }
            
            // Archive the Snyk scan report
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting error Archiving artifacts
No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**". Configuration error?

expection is be able to generate a report file in xml or json format and be able to publish the same.